# Suma de resultados de SubQuery en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql, transact-sql

Estoy necesitando sumar el resultado de tres subquery de la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT EMPLEADOS.Legajo as Legajo, EMPLEADOS.Nombre as Nombre,
(Select SUM((LEFT(HORAS1.Auto,2)*60+RIGHT(HORAS1.Auto,2)) - (LEFT(HORAS1.Auto2,2)*60+RIGHT(HORAS1.Auto2,2))) From HORAS1,TIPOHORA Where HORAS1.Legajo = EMPLEADOS.Legajo and HORAS1.Fecha >= '20190108' and HORAS1.Fecha <= '20200408' and HORAS1.FicHora = TIPOHORA.THoCodi and TIPOHORA.THoCtaH = 1 and HORAS1.Auto2 < HORAS1.Auto) AS Extras,
(Select SUM(LEFT(HORAS3.Horas,2)*60+RIGHT(HORAS3.Horas,2))From HORAS3,NOVEDAD Where HORAS3.Legajo = EMPLEADOS.Legajo and HORAS3.Fecha >= '20190108' and HORAS3.Fecha <= '20200408' and HORAS3.FicNove > 0 and HORAS3.FicNove = NOVEDAD.NovCodi and NOVEDAD.NovTiCo = 1) AS Franco1,
(Select SUM(LEFT(HORAS3.Horas,2)*60+RIGHT(HORAS3.Horas,2))From HORAS3,NOVEDAD Where HORAS3.Legajo = EMPLEADOS.Legajo and HORAS3.Fecha >= '20190108' and HORAS3.Fecha <= '20200408' and HORAS3.FicNove > 0 and HORAS3.FicNove = NOVEDAD.NovCodi and NOVEDAD.NovTiCo = 4) as Franco2,
(Select SUM(LEFT(HORAS3.Horas,2)*60+RIGHT(HORAS3.Horas,2))From HORAS3,NOVEDAD Where HORAS3.Legajo = EMPLEADOS.Legajo and HORAS3.Fecha >= '20190108' and HORAS3.Fecha <= '20200408' and HORAS3.FicNove > 0 and HORAS3.FicNove = NOVEDAD.NovCodi and NOVEDAD.NovTiCo = 2) as Jor1,
(Select SUM(LEFT(HORAS3.Horas,2)*60+RIGHT(HORAS3.Horas,2))From HORAS3,NOVEDAD Where HORAS3.Legajo = EMPLEADOS.Legajo and HORAS3.Fecha >= '20190108' and HORAS3.Fecha <= '20200408' and HORAS3.FicNove > 0 and HORAS3.FicNove = NOVEDAD.NovCodi and NOVEDAD.NovTiCo = 5) as Jor2
FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE EMPLEADOS.Legajo >= 1
ORDER BY EMPLEADOS.Legajo
```

Lo que necesito es una columna con la suma o resta del resultado Extras, Franco1 y Jor1. 
Si alguien puede orientarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! esta pregunta la hicieron hace un rato...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues hay que empezar por quitar las subconsultas del listado de columnas. Para eso podemos utilizar la instrucción `APPLY`. Aprovechando, también combinamos las 4 subconsultas casi identicas en una sola mediante un agregado condicional. Así, tenemos 2 fuentes de datos adicionales con sus propias columnas y con las cuales podemos hacer las operaciones necesarias.

```
SELECT E.Legajo as Legajo, 
    E.Nombre as Nombre,
    Ex.Extras,
    S.Franco1,
    S.Franco2,
    S.Jor1,
    S.Jor2,
    Res = Ex.Extras + S.Franco1 +S.Franco2
FROM EMPLEADOS E
CROSS APPLY (Select SUM( CASE WHEN N.NovTiCo = 1 THEN LEFT(H3.Horas,2)*60+RIGHT(H3.Horas,2) ELSE 0 END) AS Franco1,
                    SUM( CASE WHEN N.NovTiCo = 4 THEN LEFT(H3.Horas,2)*60+RIGHT(H3.Horas,2) ELSE 0 END) AS Franco2,
                    SUM( CASE WHEN N.NovTiCo = 2 THEN LEFT(H3.Horas,2)*60+RIGHT(H3.Horas,2) ELSE 0 END) AS Jor1,
                    SUM( CASE WHEN N.NovTiCo = 5 THEN LEFT(H3.Horas,2)*60+RIGHT(H3.Horas,2) ELSE 0 END) AS Jor2
            From HORAS3 H3
            JOIN NOVEDAD N ON H3.FicNove = N.NovCodi 
            Where H3.Legajo = E.Legajo 
            and H3.Fecha >= '20190108' 
            and H3.Fecha <= '20200408' 
            and H3.FicNove > 0 ) S
CROSS APPLY (Select SUM((LEFT(H1.Auto,2)*60+RIGHT(H1.Auto,2)) - (LEFT(H1.Auto2,2)*60+RIGHT(H1.Auto2,2)))  AS Extras
            From HORAS1 H1
            JOIN TIPOHORA TH ON H1.FicHora = TH.THoCodi 
            Where H1.Legajo = E.Legajo 
            and H1.Fecha >= '20190108' 
            and H1.Fecha <= '20200408' 
            and TH.THoCtaH = 1 
            and H1.Auto2 < H1.Auto) Ex
WHERE E.Legajo >= 1
ORDER BY E.Legajo;
```

No es la única forma de hacerlo, pero es algo que brinda eficiencia y orden a la consulta.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Luis. Lo voy a probar ye te comento como me fue..Saludos

Comment: Gracias Luis. Me funciono bien el arreglo. ¿Como puedo filtrar el resultado final de la query? Es decir, poder filtrar que el Resultado sea distinto a 0. AND Res <> 0. Y de esta forma solo obtener registros donde mi columna dinámica tenga datos..

Comment: Puedes agregar simplemente la condición usando la fórmula que ya tienes `Ex.Extras + S.Franco1 +S.Franco2 <>0`

Comment: Excelente. Gracias